# How to manually set CPU Fan Speed in Debian Linux?

Tags: debian, cpu, amd, fan, sensors

As my CPU cooler fan broke on a setup with older hardware, I had to replace it with a similar fan, which unfortunately is pretty noisy.

I am using the following system:

- Mainboard Gigabyte F2A88X-Up4
- CPU AMD A10-7850k radeon r7
- Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch) 64-bit

The fan is permanently running at 3770 RPM and I am looking for a way to manually reduce the speed.

There is an option in the BIOS to set the fan to a "silent" mode, but it does not have any effect.

I then installed `lm-sensors` and `fancontrol`.

Running the sensors I get the following output:

```
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:           N/A  (crit =  95.09 W)

it8620-isa-0228
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +0.70 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in1:          +1.50 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in2:          +2.03 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in3:          +2.05 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in4:          +2.05 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in5:          +2.23 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
in6:          +2.23 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +3.06 V)
3VSB:         +3.29 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +6.12 V)
Vbat:         +2.69 V  
fan1:        3770 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan2:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan3:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan4:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
fan5:           0 RPM  (min =    0 RPM)
temp1:        +22.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp2:         -8.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = thermistor
temp3:        +13.0°C  (low  = +127.0°C, high = +127.0°C)  sensor = Intel PECI
temp4:        +45.0°C  
temp5:        +45.0°C  
temp6:        +45.0°C  
intrusion0:  ALARM

radeon-pci-0008
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        -11.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:         +0.0°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                       (crit = +80.0°C, hyst = +79.0°C)
```

I then ran the fancontrol configuration script with `pwmconfig`:

```
   hwmon0 is it8620
   hwmon1 is k10temp
   hwmon2 is fam15h_power
   hwmon3 is radeon

Found the following PWM controls:
   hwmon0/pwm1           current value: 0
   hwmon0/pwm2           current value: 0
   hwmon0/pwm3           current value: 0
   hwmon0/pwm4           current value: 255
   hwmon0/pwm5           current value: 255

Giving the fans some time to reach full speed...
Found the following fan sensors:
   hwmon0/fan1_input     current speed: 3792 RPM
   hwmon0/fan2_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon0/fan3_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon0/fan4_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
   hwmon0/fan5_input     current speed: 0 ... skipping!
```

So I am trying to reduce the speed of `hwmon0/fan1_input`.

Running the test, which did not stop my CPU fan, I got the following result:

```
  hwmon0/fan1_input ... speed was 3792 now 3750
    no correlation

No correlations were detected.
There is either no fan connected to the output of hwmon0/pwm1,
or the connected fan has no rpm-signal connected to one of
the tested fan sensors. (Note: not all motherboards have
the pwm outputs connected to the fan connectors,
check out the hardware database on http://www.almico.com/forumindex.php)

Did you see/hear a fan stopping during the above test (n)?
```

Based on this result I assume that I cannot control my CPU fan with `fancontrol`?

Or is it possible to write a manual configuration for the fan in `/etc/fancontrol` despite the previous output?

I would appreciate your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

**This question has an**  [Answer here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/22108/how-to-control-fan-speed)

> Please check the thread. I hope it will help you.

You can also check the links below for more information

[fancontrol manpages](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/fancontrol/fancontrol.8.en.html)

[Ubuntu forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=42737)